# Kendo UI Scheduler: Custom view and edit behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-ui-mvc

I've been looking into this for a few days now and searched the forums high and low. Both in stack overflow, as well as Telerik's own forums, to no avail.

I'm using a Kendo UI scheduler component in an MVC application. Below is part of the index.cshtml that creates the scheduler.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<TaskViewModel>()
            .Name("scheduler")
            .Views(views => { views.CustomView("ThreeDayView"); })
            .DataSource(d => d
                .Read("Read", "Home")
                .Create("Create", "Home")
                .Destroy("Destroy", "Home")
                .Update("Update", "Home")
            )
    )
```

In this scheduler I'm using a custom view defined below.  This works fine in making the scheduler only show 3 days at a time. However the next day and previous day functionality doesn't work.  I'm assuming I have to overwrite the previousday and nextday functionality, but am not sure how.  What I expect to happen is for the view to advance 1 day at a time (i.e. April 16 - 18 moves to April 17 - 19).

Also I am wanting to add custom edit functionality. I know this might sound a bit weird, but I don't actually want anyone to be able to edit, add, or remove anything.  Simply use the scheduler as a sort of display, and then perform some operation when the task / event is clicked on, I want to do something other then opening the edit window (i.e set some variable) I think this is done with overwriting the editable function in the below jscript, but again am not sure how.  Any help and/or examples are greatly appreciated

```
var ThreeDayView = kendo.ui.MultiDayView.extend({
            options: {
                selectedDateFormat: "{0:D} - {1:D}"
            },

            name: "ThreeDayView",

            calculateDateRange: function () {
                //create a range of dates to be shown within the view
                var selectedDate = this.options.date,
                    start = kendo.date.dayOfWeek(selectedDate, this.calendarInfo().firstDay, -1),
                    idx, length,
                    dates = [];

                for (idx = 0, length = 3; idx < length; idx++) {
                    dates.push(start);
                    start = kendo.date.nextDay(start);
                }

                this._render(dates);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this answer from the telerik boards, thought I'd share in case anyone else runs across this problem.

> In order the custom view to behave as you have described, the nextDate
>   method should be overridden to return the next to the start date. Also
>   with the current implementation the view always starts at the first
>   day of the week, which does not comply to the behavior you are looking
>   for:
>
> ```
> var ThreeDayView = kendo.ui.MultiDayView.extend({
>
>     nextDate: function () {
>         return kendo.date.nextDay(this.startDate());
>     },
>
>     options: {
>         selectedDateFormat: "{0:D} - {1:D}"
>     },
>
>     name: "ThreeDayView",
>
>     calculateDateRange: function () {
>         //create a range of dates to be shown within the view
>         var //selectedDate = this.options.date,
>             // start = kendo.date.dayOfWeek(selectedDate, this.calendarInfo().firstDay, -1),
>             start = this.options.date,
>             idx, length,
>             dates = [];
>
>         for (idx = 0, length = 3; idx < length; idx++) {
>             dates.push(start);
>             start = kendo.date.nextDay(start);
>         }
>
>         this._render(dates);
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> Regarding the edit functionality. It will be easier to use the
>   scheduler edit event to prevent the popup from showing and to add the
>   custom logic.
>
> ```
> @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<TaskViewModel>()
>             .Name("scheduler")
>             .Events(events => events.Edit("edit"))
>  )
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     function edit(e) {
>         e.preventDefault();
>         // do something here;
>     }
> </script>
> ```
>
> Regards,
>    Rosen

Comment: Althought I have implemented this custom view, it doest not show my events on itself. Why it happened?

Comment: @esquare:: Facing same issue. have you found any fix?