# Kendo UI Scheduler-Select a range consisted to completely months when it is at the Month view

Tags: kendo-ui, scheduler

I am using Kendo UI Scheduler. I configured it like it would have a Month view. I would like to select a range consists two months. Can I select these ranges? as I saw, the Scheduler, whenever We mention the Months, allows selecting only 14 days... İn essence, I would like to select days through the months.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if extending the month view is exactly possible or not. But, creating a custom view may be a solution. Have a look on this [**LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117494/kendo-ui-scheduler-custom-view-and-edit-behavior). Also have a look what telerik admin says about it [**HERE**](http://www.telerik.com/forums/extend-kendo-ui-monthview).

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not solve the problem through your answer... I hope, I could tell properly what I mean. please think, you want to select a date range conducted 35 days. 31 days are from March and 4 days are from April. You should do selecting operation with your mouse, but the Scheduler widget does not approve it. Could I tell properly? Actutally, when you nex tto April view, it does not view your before selecting belongs to March. I should select these big date ranges.

Comment: Got your point. Will update here when I find any specific answer.

Comment: Can I contact you via mail for detailed presentation this example?

Comment: Sure.My mail id: satyaranjan219@gmail.com

Comment: I have sent an email. Could you check it?

Comment: Yeah. I have shared my skype id in my reply to your mail. Lets discuss there.